# How do I avoid using an async class when using gwt dto?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-ext

Can anyone please explain how I can avoid using an *aync class* when using `dto` to serialize an object in a service?

Comment: can you please further articulate your question?

Comment: I agree, you need to expand your answer a bit, provide an example of what your talking about and just put more words into it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, DTOs are only for passing data to the client side in a GWT application, when you can't pass the server side object directly. DTOs have nothing to do with the async classes, which the GWT compiler needs for RPC service calls.